# Firebase Firestore API does not work on just Flutter

Tags: flutter

Firebase Firestore API does not work on Flutter only. I have tried the same url on my browser and python and they work like a charm. I could not figure out why it does not work Flutter.

API_url = https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/weathersense-daa83/databases/(default)/documents/weather_data/latest_data

The code I wrote in the HTTP get request in Flutter

```
var response = await http.post(
                  'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/weathersense-daa83/databases/(default)/documents/weather_data/latest_data');
              print(response);
              print(response.body);
```

The output that I got

```
I/flutter (15665): {
I/flutter (15665):   "error": {
I/flutter (15665):     "code": 400,
I/flutter (15665):     "message": "Document parent name \"projects/weathersense-daa83/databases/(default)/documents/weather_data\" lacks \"/\" at index 70.",
I/flutter (15665):     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
I/flutter (15665):   }
I/flutter (15665): }
```

The same url on browser retrieves the data.

```
{
  "name": "projects/weathersense-daa83/databases/(default)/documents/weather_data/latest_data",
  "fields": {
    "timestamp": {
      "integerValue": "20201106131503"
    },
    "rain_intensity": {
      "doubleValue": 0
    },
    "wind_speed": {
      "doubleValue": 0
    },
    "hail_duration": {
      "doubleValue": 0
    },
    "humidity": {
      "doubleValue": 57.2
    },
    "supply_voltage": {
      "doubleValue": 13.9
    },
    "rain_accumulation": {
      "doubleValue": 0
    },
    "ref_voltage": {
      "doubleValue": 3.615
    },
    "rain_duration": {
      "doubleValue": 0
    },
    "internal_temp": {
      "doubleValue": 23.6
    },
    "temp": {
      "doubleValue": 23.4
    },
    "pressure": {
      "doubleValue": 1002.6
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2020-10-31T20:15:04.479800Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-11-06T05:15:03.935166Z"
}
```

Comment: Use GET request it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `'GET'` request instead of `'POST'`, cause thats what browsers do.

```
var response = await http.get(
                  'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/weathersense-daa83/databases/(default)/documents/weather_data/latest_data');
              print(response);
              print(response.body);
```